# TSQL Rellenar valores nulls con el último valor no null en una misma columna

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de rellenar registros de una columna donde tengo valores nulls de forma entrecortada con el último valor no null de la misma columna (de abajo hacia arriba). Les muestro una imagen de lo que quiero . Uso TSQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pues debes hacer una subconsulta como la siguiente, donde se obtiene el valor del estado en el periodo más alto (más reciente) y lo pone en los periodos donde hay el valor `null` en el campo estado.

```
UPDATE tabla SET ESTADO = b.ESTADO
FROM tabla a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT ESTADO, MAX(PERIODO)
   FROM tabla
   WHERE ESTADO IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY ESTADO
) b on 1=1
WHERE a.ESTADO IS NULL
```

LA CONSULTA ME DEVUELVE EL RESULTADO DE FORMA ERRONEA; SI TUVIERAS OTRA OPCION TE LO AGARADECERIA

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]